# SPARQL-Query results invalid?

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I run a Virtuoso Server and missed a number of results when making a SPARQL-Select request. I tracked it down and find a really strange behaviour, that I cannot explain.

But to start from the beginning.

The endpoint I query can be found at http://creativeartefact.org/sparql

I) Check for a specific triple:

```
ASK WHERE {
<http://creativeartefact.org/mbrainzImport/f18e677a-4051-486a-aa64-d9a3bfef90af>
<http://creativeartefact.org/ontology/represents>
<http://creativeartefact.org/mbrainzImport/35ed9f2a-6ce4-44ca-9c7a-967377b0e007>. }
```

The query returns **TRUE**

II) Now getting a bit more unspecific:

```
ASK WHERE {
?s
<http://creativeartefact.org/ontology/represents>
<http://creativeartefact.org/mbrainzImport/35ed9f2a-6ce4-44ca-9c7a-967377b0e007>. }
```

If the first returns true, the second shall do as well, shouldn't it? But it doesn't. It return **FALSE**!

If I replace the predicate or the object with a variable, it returns true as expected. Only when setting a variable for the subject, it returns false.

That the data really exists in the triple store can be tested by running the query

```
SELECT * WHERE {
?s
?p
<http://creativeartefact.org/mbrainzImport/35ed9f2a-6ce4-44ca-9c7a-967377b0e007>. }
```

You will see, that both results comw with p = http://creativeartefact.org/ontology/represents - which is exactly the predicate I am asking for in the former query.

To make it even more strange, there ARE triples with the aforementioned format, that return the triples:

```
select * {
?s
<http://creativeartefact.org/ontology/represents>
<http://creativeartefact.org/mbrainzImport/e4003568-5645-4ee1-abd0-2e8156272e59>. }
```

Any idea, what is happening here?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: I notice in your second query, if you change it to `select * where { ?s ... }`, there are no results.  Are you *sure* that triple is actually in your data?

Comment: They are, just replace the <../represents> predicate with a ?p (I updated the question to reflect it)

Comment: I see what you mean.  There's definitely something odd with Virtuoso on this.  You should probably put together a minimal example (e.g., start from an empty store, execute an insert to put data into the graph, and then a query to show the unexpected results) and email the Virtuoso mailing list.  This seems like it's almost certainly a bug, and something that Virtuoso devs would have to speak to.

Comment: To make things even more strange ... there are triples with the same structure like the ones above, where the query returns the expected result. (Updated the question with one example) So I guess it will be difficult to reproduce. I already made a post in the virtuoso forum.

Comment: That data is no longer present for quick testing... Is this still an issue, now you're running VOS `07.20.3215` (of Feb 16 2016)? (Worth noting, source [is at `.3217` as of April](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/blob/develop/7/ChangeLog), and there have been many [more commits since](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/commits/develop/7), so you may want to update further.)

Answer (score 0):

The Virtuoso being used is an original 07.00.3203 build from 2013.

I would suggest upgrading to the latest Virtuoso 07.10.3211, [open source](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource) or [commercial](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/download/), depending on which is in use here, and see if the problem persists ...

Comment: While the suggestion to upgrade is usually not a bad one, do you hae a speciifc reason to think that this bug will be fixes in that release?  E.g., was there a particular bug that was fixed that seems relevant?  (Otherwise, I'd suggest that this should be a comment, not an answer.)